# R Markdown thesisdown fix(?) indentation

Tags: indentation, templates, thesis, rmarkdown

Using [thesisdown](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown)  to write my Masterthesis I was wondering about the default indentations of the package: If you check the pictures below, all the pages (of the default 'knitted' thesisdown rmd-files) have different indentations (holds also for the toc).

On a first glance my guess was that pages with a heading have a certain indentation, whereas the following pages don't have any indentation. This theory also holds for the toc. But imo it doesn't hold for the first picture.

So I ask myself: is this indentation behaviour intended or is it an 'unwanted' side-effect? And is there a way to unify the indentations for all pages?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The indentation is to highlight  a new paragraph, but after a title this  is so obvious that have non sense indent the first paragraph. Although this is not the norm in some languages, in English your output is very correct. The wrong here is that there are clear paragraph skips in  page 7 but no in the others, the `$2 \pi$` of the same page,  do not use `round()` for the SD of speed (really matter that 7 decimals?),  and do not use `colorlinks` option for the hyperref package (except if you really like the ugly link boxes, of course).

Comment: This is coming from the `twoside` class option (e.g. https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown/blob/8f66a482e6188db526622986fb36ed0ffa4bcee1/inst/rmarkdown/templates/thesis/skeleton/template.tex#L27) which uses different indentation according to reflect binding.  It looks like this is effectively hardcoded in `thesisdown` (https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown/issues/95).